# PyTorch's CrossEntropyLoss - how to deal with the sequence length dimension with transformers?

Tags: pytorch

I'm training a transformer model for text generation.

let's assume:

```
vocab size = 100
embbeding size = 50
max sequence length = 30
batch size = 32
loss = cross entropy loss
```

the last layer in the model is a fully connected layer,
mapping from shape `[30, 32, 50]` to `[30, 32, 100]`.
the idea is that each of the last 30 sequences in the first dimension, I have a target vector I want to calculate loss with.

the issue is that based on the docs, this loss only excepts 2 dims on the prediction and one on the target - so how can I fit my 3D prediction into it?
(and 2D target?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `torch.BCELoss()` instead (Binary cross entropy). This expects input and target to be the same size but they can be any size, and should fall within the range [0,1]. It performs cross-entropy loss element-wise.

EDIT: if you expect only one element from the vocab to be output, then you should use `CrossEntropyLoss` and instead encode your labels as a 1D vector rather than a 2D vector (i.e. do 1-hot decoding). `BCE` treats each element in the output for a single example as independent from the others, which is not a valid assumption for a multi-class style problem. I originally misread and thought the final output was an embedding, rather than an element from the vocabulary, hence my original suggestion.

Comment: so, why are ppl using regular Cross Entropy loss anyway?

Comment: Cross entropy loss is convenient if your network is say outputting K class confidences for an object (i.e. target is a one-hot vector). The training data likely has the label in the form of an integer (which indicates the correct class index) rather than a 1-hot vector (which you would need to compute BCE loss for networks output). Cross Entropy loss is convenient because it skips the (admittedly somewhat trivial ) step of computing the one-hot target vector. However, pytorch's cross entropy loss is thus not suitable for sequence prediction for this reason, and you should instead use BCE\

Comment: Binary cross-entropy and cross-entropy are different things. You can't just substitute one for another to make the shapes work.

Comment: @jxmorris yeah you are mostly correct about this. The choice of the particular loss function has more to do with the assumed structure of the data, as selecting from amongst the set of loss functions that DO have the correct dimension selects the functional relationship that the model learns, any of which IS technically valid. But empirically different loss functions yield better results for different problems. Since the problem being solved here is essentially Multi-class classification, the assumed output independence of BCE is probably a bad assumption. I edited my answer for posterity.